With new 24.04, how can I stop my screen from frequently going black, while in use
Since upgrading to 24.04, my screen frequently goes black, while I am using it. I find this happens especially when my cursor is on the edge of the screen. It is easily refreshed. I have told screen saver to never activate and have even uninstalled screensaver, which doesn't help.

Are you using NVidia graphics card?

In am using Intel graphics
